# git repository mirror with detached head causes error: GH002

Tags: git, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, mirror

The following code is running in an Azure Pipeline to mirror the source to another git repository.

```
git remote add --mirror=fetch mirror MIRROR_REPO

git push mirror --progress --prune +refs/remotes/origin/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

When the agent runs it checks out the code at a specific commit which results in a detached head which has the name of the commit SHA. This are logs produced by the agent:

```
 * [new ref]           6ADFB183A4A2C94A2F92DAB5ADE762A47889A5A1 -> origin/6ADFB183A4A2C94A2F92DAB5ADE762A47889A5A1
git checkout --progress --force 6ADFB183A4A2C94A2F92DAB5ADE762A47889A5A1
Note: switching to '6ADFB183A4A2C94A2F92DAB5ADE762A47889A5A1'
```

I guess that's the reason the `git push mirror` command fails with the following error:

```
remote: error: GH002: Sorry, branch or tag names consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed.        
remote: error: Invalid branch or tag name "6ADFB183A4A2C94A2F92DAB5ADE762A47889A5A1"
```

I'm looking for a method to push all branches and tags from my source repository to my mirror repository every time the pipeline runs.

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: it looks like you must not have such strange branch names. Note that commit names use lower-case hex characters, not uppercase hex characters. Regardless, it looks like a bad idea to use them as branch names.

Comment: yes it's pretty clear, the probleme here is that the name is generated by Azure DevOps and it's not really a branch but a head in a detached state, otherwise i would just rename the branch

Comment: The line `* [new ref]` indicates that it *has* create a reference, not just used a detached-HEAD. (A detached-HEAD might work, but the ref definitely doesn't. The fact that it doesn't say `* [new branch]` is interesting: it may have created a non-branch ref. Either way GitHub is rejecting it though.) Not sure what you can do about this here; the agent is behaving badly.

Comment: Hi @nor0x. Could you please refer to the answer and try to skip the default checkout step? Feel free to let me know if the answer could give you some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> remote: error: GH002: Sorry, branch or tag names consisting of 40 hex characters are not allowed.

Based on my test, I could reproduce the same issue.

In azure devops default checkout step, it will set the commitid as the `[New Ref]`.  Since this is the default step, we cannot interfere with how it works.

For a workaround, you could skip the default checkout step(`- checkout: none`) and run the git command to checkout all branches and tags.

Here is my sample:

```
steps:
- checkout: none

- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      git clone --mirror  sourcerepo

      cd $(build.sourcesdirectory)\reponame
      
      git remote add --mirror=fetch mirror MIRROR_REPO
      
      git push mirror --progress --prune +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* +refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*
```

Then it will push all branches and tags to Github successfully.

Comment: thanks for your reply @Kevin Lu-MSFT any chance the - checkout: none step could be configured with the GUI editor of Azure Pipelines, unfortunately i’m currently stuck with the visual editor.

Comment: Hi @nor0x. For the GUI editor of Azure Pipelines, you could set the pipeline variable: **Build.SyncSources = false**. Then the checkout step will be skipped.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't happen because the branch name is strange, as was mentioned in the comments.
It also happens for more conventional names.
The error seems to be as weird as it says: branch names cannot have exactly 40 characters. They can be shorter or longer.

This is not an answer to this particular problem, since the branch name was created automatically.
But other users (like me) might end up in this page due to the same error.
The workaround, for us, was to make the branch name one character longer or shorter.